# Most efficient inductor : Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I don't know how inductance and the strength of the magnetic field produced in an inductor relate.

The most efficient multilayer selonoidal inductor design (using a constant length of wire) is Brooks coil.
[image: cross section view of Brooks coil]

**Does this mean the most efficient magnetic field is produced by the same design?**

(i.e if I'm given a predetermined constant length of wire and a constant available current, is the Brooks coil the one producing the strongest magnetic field ?)

If not, is there a rule to follow or should I just lean on many many try-measure-alter cylces to find a relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how inductance and the strength of the magnetic field
> produced in an inductor relate.

This is the easy part of your question. The inductance is just a measure of how much energy is stored in the magnetic field. If you have an inductor with current flowing through it the energy stored in the magnetic field is just E=1/2*L*I^2 where E is energy, L is inductance, and I is the current.

But maybe by strength of magnetic field you mean you mean the maximum intensity of the magnetic field at any point in the inductor? If this is what you are going for and not the maximum possible inductance then probably going with a really small diameter coil would make the field strength inside of it greater.